# How to Output Edm.DateTime Without Time?

Tags: sapui5

```
<m:Text text="{
  path: 'Begda',
  type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime',
  formatOptions: {
    style: 'short'
  },
  constraints: {
    nullable: true,
    displayFormat: 'Date'
  }
}"/>
```

From the documentation I understood that I should use `displayFormat: 'Date'` to show the date only. The expected output is a localized display of day/month/year (or in another localized order).

The output that I get is `17/08/16 02:00`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OData Edm.DateTime - How to Display Date Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210037/odata-edm-datetime-how-to-display-date-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. In order to display the date only..:

1. Same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47472757/5846045), you need to replace the regular type with the **`odata` type:** <s>`sap.ui.model.type.DateTime`</s> --> [`sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime).

   > This class represents the OData V2 primitive type [Edm.DateTime](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/#AbstractTypeSystem).
2. And then use this constraint, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47551731/5846045):

   ```
   constraints: {
     displayFormat: 'Date'
   }
   ```

   About the `displayFormat: 'Date'`:

   > In this case, **only the date part is used**, the time part is always 00:00:00, and the time zone is UTC to avoid time-zone-related problems.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the pattern property and change the type property for sap.ui.model.type.Date:

```
<Text text="{path: '/someDate',
            type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
            formatOptions: {
                source: {
                    pattern: 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.AAAZ'   <-- Source property is optional
                },
            pattern: 'yyyy/MM/dd'
            }
        }" />
```