# Date Mismatch in UI5 Application

Tags: sapui5

I have a [DatePicker](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker) in UI5 application. My server is in Australia. When I create any record in IST time, it is working fine. But when a user tries to create any record in Australia, the date value is incremented by 1. That is `"31"` coming as `"32"`. Do I need to consider the time zone?

Comment: Let us know, by clicking on the checkmark, if one of the answers was helpful to resolve the issue. Read _[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)_

Answer (score 2):

UI5 already takes care of handling dates properly if you use the binding type `sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime` in the `value` binding definition of your `DatePicker`.

- **Display** the date in UTC by adding `UTC: true` to the `formatOptions` *(Optional).*
- **Store** the date in UTC by adding `displayFormat: 'Date'` to the `constraints`.

  > In `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel`, this type (`sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime`) is represented as a *Date*. With the constraint `displayFormat: 'Date'`, the time zone is UTC and **the time part is ignored.**
  >
  > (...) In this case, only the date part is used, the time part is always 00:00:00, and the time zone is UTC **to avoid time-zone-related problems.**

Here is a live demo:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataModel",
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
], function(ODataModel, XMLView) {
  "use strict";

  const model = new ODataModel({
    serviceUrl: [
      "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/", // proxy
      "https://services.odata.org/V2/(S(SO46024229))/OData/OData.svc",
    ].join(""),
    defaultBindingMode: "TwoWay",
    preliminaryContext: true,
    tokenHandling: false, // service does not provide CSRF tokens
  });

  Promise.all([
    sap.ui.getCore().loadLibrary("sap.m", true),
    sap.ui.getCore().loadLibrary("sap.ui.unified", true),
  ]).then(() => XMLView.create({
    definition: `<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" height="100%">
      <DatePicker id="dp" xmlns="sap.m" width="auto" placeholder="Date"
        binding="{
          path: '/Products(0)',
          parameters: {
            select: 'ID,ReleaseDate'
          }
        }"
        value="{
          path: 'ReleaseDate',
          type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime',
          constraints: {
            displayFormat: 'Date',
            nullable: false
          }
        }"
      />
    </mvc:View>`,
    models: model,
    afterInit: function() {
      const fn = e => e.getSource().getBindingContext().getModel().submitChanges();
      this.byId("dp").attachChange(fn);
    },
  }).then(view => {
    const messageManager = sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager();
    messageManager.registerObject(view.placeAt("content"), true);
  }));
}));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-modules="sap/ui/thirdparty/datajs"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="rendering"
></script><body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

The internal module [datajs](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/thirdparty/datajs.js) parses the incoming `Emd.DateTime` string in native JS date object, and the module `sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime` stores it in the model as long as the *constraints* aren't violated.

---

### Reference

- Documentation topic: *[Date and Time Related Controls: Data Binding](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/e1ddc69c01474faf830a522db8c9238a)*
- API reference: [`sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime)

Answer (score 0):

```
   prepareDatesToDisplay: function(oDate){ //to display dates from backend
                var oTempDate = new Date(oDate);
                oDate = new Date(oTempDate.getTime() + oTempDate.getTimezoneOffset() * (60000));
                return oDate;
    },
    changeDateToUTC: function(oDate){ //for sending dates to backend
                var oTempDate = new Date(oDate.setHours("00","00","00","00"));
                oDate = new Date(oTempDate.getTime() + oTempDate.getTimezoneOffset() * (-60000));
                return oDate;
    },
```