# Why is the datepicker not recognizing wrong format?

Tags: sapui5

I have a datepicker that was created with the following code snippet:

```js
return new sap.m.DatePicker(sId, {
    dateValue: `{${sPath}}`,
    valueFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy",
    displayFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy"
});
```

Typing wrong weird stuff into the field:
[image]
It does not recognize the invalid format.

But when I tried to write in [this example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.DatePicker/preview), it does recognize.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which format is the value behind the `sPath` in model stored? Is it a JS-date object? Is it in string? With which model are you working? JSONModel? Or ODataModel? If it's the latter model, let me know if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/47551731/5846045

Comment: The value of the `sPath` is `CharInput>/ZPM_TEST_6`. It is a JSON object it has the type null at initial.

Comment: The value should be the type of `Date`. That because, I set it to `null` on the initialization point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const oDatePicker = new DatePicker(sId).bindValue({
  path: sPath,
  type: new DateType({ // "sap/ui/model/type/Date"
    pattern: "dd-MM-yyyy",
  })
});
const messageManager = sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager();
messageManager.registerObject(oDatePicker, true);
return oDataPicker;
```

1. If working with data binding, you'll need to bind the `value` property instead of `dateValue`.

   > <sup>[API reference: `sap.m.DatePicker`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker)</sup>
   >
   > - Use the `value` property if you want to bind the DatePicker to a model using the `sap.ui.model.type.Date`.
   > - Use the `dateValue` property if the date is already provided as a JavaScript Date object or you want to work with a JavaScript Date object. (...) Although possible to bind it, the recommendation is **not** to do it. **When binding is needed, use `value` property instead.**
2. And finally, register the control to the MessageManager or [enable `handleValidation`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/a90d93df5a024e8bb18826b699c9aaa7). UI5 will then take care of displaying the error message if the input could not be parsed or violates given constraints.

Answer (score 0):

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.DatePicker/code/Group.controller.js

```
handleChange: function (oEvent) {
        var oText = this.byId("T1");
        var oDP = oEvent.oSource;
        var sValue = oEvent.getParameter("value");
        var bValid = oEvent.getParameter("valid");
        this._iEvent++;
        oText.setText("Change - Event " + this._iEvent + ": DatePicker " + oDP.getId() + ":" + sValue);

        if (bValid) {
            oDP.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.None);
        } else {
            oDP.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
        }
    }
```

this is the change handler used in the sample you have to implement the error handling by yourself