# DatePicker value mismatchg in SAP Gateway server

Tags: date, timezone, sapui5, mismatch

I am trying to post date value to backend. But the value is sometimes increment/decrement by 1 in sap gateway. I have tried many possible solutions. But no luck. I am working between two time zones EST and IST. How to reoslve this?

```
    var syFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({
            pattern: "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",
            UTC : true
        });
        var f = syFormat.format(d);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date Mismatch in UI5 Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46024229/date-mismatch-in-ui5-application)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47551731/5846045

Answer (score 0):

Is there some purpose behind setting UTC to be true? Because due to this, the time is being formatted and parsed according to UTC instead of your local timezone.

You can try to perform the formatting without setting the 'UTC' parameter.