# OData Edm.DateTime - How to Display Date Only

Tags: sapui5

In UI5, my OData is returning the date in the following format:

> Mon Apr 09 2018 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

I would like to format it to: `09/04/2018`

I have tried the following without any results:

```xml
<Text text="{                            
  path: 'MyoDataService>ExecuteDay',
  type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
  formatOptions: {
    pattern: 'yyyy/MM/dd'
  }
}"/>
```

Another example I have tried and It is not working neither:

```xml
<Text text="{
  path:'MyoDataService>ExecuteDay',
  type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
  formatOptions: {
    source: {
      pattern: 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'
    },
    pattern: 'dd MMM yyyy'
  }
}" />
```

The controller where the model gets created looks like this:

```js
onInit: function() {
  var sServiceUrl = "http://myurl/myservice";
  var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl,true);
  var oJsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
  oModel.read("/MyEntitySet", null, null, true, function(oData, response) {
    oJsonModel.setData(oData);
  });
  this.getView().setModel(oJsonModel, "MyEntitySet");
},
```

Comment: You'd like to have "dd/MM/YYYY" but in the coding: "yyyy/MM/dd" :)

Comment: Is it still not working with the answers below? What kind of EDM type does the `ExecuteDay` actually have? Were you talking about OData V4? What do you exactly mean by "not working"? What kind of results do you get if you apply the [solution shared below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50212568/5846045)?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann EDM type is DateTime. I am using oData V2. Not working means that I am getting the information as "blank" in my table.

Comment: @Juan I see. The "blank" space usually indicates that the binding path is invalid and thus couldn't be resolved. You might have a typo in the `path`,  set the [model on Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42251431/5846045), or the data is plainly `null` or `""`. Either way, it's not the matter of `formatOptions` or `type`. Please, take a look at the first-aid kit topic ["Content or Control Is Not Visible"](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/492d9d93effd4229a5a89cb20124553c).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Add Date / Time from OData Service Correctly to UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593990/how-to-add-date-time-from-odata-service-correctly-to-ui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using *OData* protocol, you'll need to use the appropriate [data type](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type) as well (instead of simple types).

Take a look at your service metadata and look for the [EDM type](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/#AbstractTypeSystem) that is assigned to the entity property. For example:

### Given

```
<Property Name="BirthDate" Type="Edm.DateTime"/>
```

<sup>OData **V2** entity property</sup>

### Property Binding (Date only)

```
<Text text="{                            
  path: 'myODataModel>BirthDate',
  type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime',
  constraints: {
    displayFormat: 'Date'
  }
}"/>
```

- The constraint `displayFormat` enables us to display only the date part of the DateTime value.

  > may be "Date", in this case only the date part is used, the time part is always 00:00:00 and the time zone is UTC to avoid time-zone-related problems. <sup>[[source]](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime)</sup>
- There is also the EDM type `Date` but it's intended to be used for OData V4 services only.

  > For an OData V2 service, use `sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime` with the constraint `displayFormat: "Date"` to display only a date. <sup>[[source]](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type.Date)</sup>
- Most of the times, there is no need to alter the `pattern` within `formatOptions` since the [framework already detects the user locale](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/91f21f176f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html#loio91f21f176f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070__section_6CAF7D95C27C487CB201CE83345AC370) and displays the date accordingly.

---

## The "not working" part

<sup>(For question author only)</sup>

As it turned out in the question, "not working" was actually referring to the data not being in the UI at all rather than data being improperly formatted.

Thanks to the [6th revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50210037/revisions), we can see that the main cause lies in the way of how the **M** in MVC was handled in `onInit`. As there are several issues, let's tackle them one by one..:

1. In order to display the data in the first place, the model names (one when setting the model and one when defining the binding path) must be identical to each other. This was, however, not the case in your code:

   > ```js
   > this.getView().setModel(/*...*/, "MyEntitySet");
   > ```

   > ```xml
   > <Text text="{
   >  path: 'MyoDataService>...'
   > ```

   The second argument in `setModel`<sup>[[API]](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/setModel)</sup> refers to the name that is used in the binding path. Since there was no model set with the name `"MyoDataService"`, the framework couldn't know that it should have retrieved the data from `"MyEntitySet"` model. For more information, please read the documentation topic [Binding Syntax](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/e2e6f4127fe4450ab3cf1339c42ee832) and the underlying topic [Binding Path](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/2888af49635949eca14fa326d04833b9) thoroughly.
2. Not sure where you got the snippet from but `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel`<sup>[[API]](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel)</sup> is an ancient module which has been [deprecated for a long time](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/03/stop-using-sap.ui.model.odata.odatamodel-aka-v1-odatamodel-its-deprecated-since-2014/). It also sends many requests synchronously which degrades UX due to the blocking behavior of the UI thread.

   > Synchronous XMLHttpRequest outside of workers is **in the process of being removed from the web platform** as it has detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. <sup>[[source]](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method)</sup>

   Please, use [v2.ODataModel](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel) instead.
3. There is no need for an intermediate JSONModel to handle backend data. JSONModel is a client-side model which is not intended to be used for handling OData related stuff. Otherwise, you're going to invent the wheel again since the ODataModel and its binding already support sending optimized requests efficiently without having to download the whole set of entities. Here is an example: [https://embed.plnkr.co/lBreXFg9ozLcvMCN](https://embed.plnkr.co/lBreXFg9ozLcvMCN?show=view%2FHome.view.xml,preview). The example also shows various binding types (Context binding, List Binding, Property Binding, etc..) and their syntax. In OData V4, you won't be even able to call `.read` directly. It's good to get used to binding OData in the view directly.

For further understanding and best practices, please follow the [Walkthrough steps](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db) carefully and try to understand every single sentence there.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help Boghyon! At the end it was a mix of many things, most of them because the way I was getting the data from the service and the model as you explained.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a formatter-function ?

```
path : 'MyoDataService>ExecuteDay',
     formatter : function(value) {
       return /* your format logic here */;
     }
```