# How to show only date in SAPUI5 DatePicker

Tags: date, formatting, sapui5

I have 2 `sap.m.DatePicker` objects in my XML view. I set the format to

> sap.ui.model.odata.type.Date

based on the documentation in the following address 
[sap.ui.model.odata.type](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type)

```
<DatePicker value="{ path: 'Validtodate', type : 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.Date'}" />
```

But still, I don't know why it shows date and time instead of date

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OData Edm.DateTime - How to Display Date Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210037/odata-edm-datetime-how-to-display-date-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually a common problem in `SAPUI5` applications. It is because of the type that you selected for your controller. Edit your XML code like this:

```
<DatePicker value="{ path: 'Validtodate', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.Date'}" />
```

Comment: This really depends on the type of the data source. If it's an OData service, using `sap.ui.model.odata.*` types is not a problem but the intended solution by UI5. E.g. if the `Validtodate` is a property of V4 type `Edm.Date`, the proper type is in fact `sap.ui.model.odata.type.Date` ([API ref](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type.Date)). The question author needs to provide more information whether the data is coming from an OData at all.

Comment: But I had exactly the same problem in oData service in SAP ERP systems.

Comment: Having problems when using the proper types suggests that the backend services were either not OData compliant or improperly configured. Anyhow, the topic [_Date and Time Related Controls: Data Binding_](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/e1ddc69c01474faf830a522db8c9238a) as well as the [API reference](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type) suggests to use `sap.ui.model.odata` types corresponding to the EDM type of the entity property.