# How to Format the Date in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

How to format the Date and time in sapui5 application. Formatter option is not working. Please suggest some idea. Shared the tried code also.

my code :

```
new sap.m.ObjectIdentifier({  width : "100%" ,
        title : "{DocDate}",
        type: new sap.ui.model.type.DateTime({pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd"})
 
    })
```

result :
[image: result]

I need result like this : 2020-09-08

If anyone has an idea or a suggestion, I'd be more than thankful if you let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OData Edm.DateTime - How to Display Date Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210037/odata-edm-datetime-how-to-display-date-only)

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```js
new sap.m.ObjectIdentifier({
  width : "100%" ,
  title : "{ path: 'DocDate' , type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: {pattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd'} }" 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To format a date in sapui5 this works as well. Check in console.

```js
// DateFormat required from the module "sap/ui/core/format/DateFormat"
DateFormat.getDateInstance({pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd"}).format(new Date());
```